# display data in table with column name

Tags: windows, forms, datagridview, datatable

I have a table with 6 locations with staff allocated to an office. How do I display them in a table windows forms with the column name but not display if empty. If I had the following.

```
office1    office2     office3    office4   office5  office 6
-------    -------     -------    -------   -------  --------
Dave       Bob                    Ed
Alan       Jeff                   John        
Tom
```

Comment: Use a `DataGridView` and after loading data hide those columns which doesn't contain any data. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes Reza that would work thank you.